# How do you get number_format() to add two decimal points on integers less than 10?

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

The price is in cents, but whenever the price is less than $10 its not adding .00!

```
              $price = (float)($cents/100);
              $price = number_format($price,2);
```

I want to be able to represent 0.00 and 0.01 and 1.01 not sure how to do this if number_format() doesnt work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

```
<?php

$prices = array(100, 10, 1, 0.10, 0.01);
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    echo money_format('%.2n', $price) . "\n";
}

// 100.00
// 10.00
// 1.00
// 0.10
// 0.01
?>
```

Comment: The more I learn about PHP, the more I expect there to be a `kitchen_sink()` function somewhere.